# How to retrieve keystroke/character mapping table from Microsoft IME program?

Tags: cjk, ime

I want to know how to retrieve the character mapping table from ms IME?

When the user key in "gao xing", ms IME will display 高兴 in Chinese.

What I want to achieve is the other way round; when user key in 高兴, the program will convert it to "gao xing". In order to do that, I need a database / mapping table for this. And I guess MS IME contains this table already, it's just the matter how i retrieve it.

Do you have any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

There is no mapping that you can retrieve as a simple table. You could look into [CEDICT](http://www.mdbg.net/chindict/chindict.php?page=cedict) for an open-source dictionary of Chinese with PinYin readings.